# What are the least permissions required for an Application Pool in IIS to serve static files?

Tags: iis-8, windows-server-2012

I am having trouble with IIS serving up static files (.html, images, CSS, etc). I first encountered the [problem with TFS](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2bd833ab-533c-4a4a-b2c4-6caf30c8609b/team-foundation-server-website-not-serving-static-files-properly), and after trying lots of different things with no success, I am now trying to figure out the cause by creating a simple site with one HTML file and seeing if I can browse it.

The server is running Windows Server 2012, IIS 8.0 and TFS 2012. I have created a local user account called *testweb* and an application pool called *My new TFS App Pool*.

[image: IIS Application Pools]

*testweb* has been added to the **IIS_IUSRS** group. The App Pool has been set to **No Managed Code**.

I've created an application called *test* under the *Default Web Site* and set it to use the new App Pool. It contains a single file called *index.html*.

[image: IIS Application]

When I try to browse the HTML page (which is just a simple Hello World page), it fails with the following HTTP Error 500 Internal Server Error:

[image: IIS Error]

I have also tried adding *testweb* to the local *Administrators* group to no avail. If I change the App Pool identity to use my own personal domain account, the page will render fine.

What changes do I need to make to the *testweb* account so that it will function properly as an App Pool identity?

Comment: Does testweb have file access permission to read c:\temp\testweb

Comment: _testweb_ is part of the local _users_ group which does have permissions to _c:\temp\testweb_. It wasn't working, so I explicitly added read permissions for _testweb_ and then it started working. That didn't make sense to me, so I removed the explicit permissions, but it continues to work. So the next thing I tried, is changing the app pool identity to an existing domain service account, but that doesn't work. I've tried viewing the effective access for the service account and it says it has read permissions to the folder. It's not making sense to me.

Comment: It may be doing something odd like only validating file permissions on appPool recycle?

Comment: I've been restarting IIS as I make changes.

Comment: After restarting Windows with the explicit permissions removed for _testweb_, the page gets the HTTP 500 error again.

Comment: Any reason why you're not using `Application Pool Identity` instead of  your `testweb` account?

Comment: Because my real problem is with a domain service account used with TFS. I was trying to replicate the problem I'm having with TFS using a simple website containing a single HTML file and a local user account.